# Scrolling to checked menu item

Tags: android, scroll, menu, menuitem, android-menu

I have a `SubMenu` with a list of checkable `MenuItems` as shown below:

[image]

The number of menu items in `SubMenu` is too long and the problem is when user selects a menu item located at the end of the list, and then reopen the `SubMenu`, menu items list is shown from the top with unchecked items and user has to scroll to bottom to see previous selection:

[image]

Now the question is, is there any way to scroll the list to show checked item? I have the same problem with `PopupMenu`.